# Consolidate Multiple Update Queries

Tags: t-sql, updates

How do I combine these two queries (updating using crosstables and criteria) to alleviate the need for using many queries within a macro?

Query 1

```
UPDATE [Master Output Table], [Input table] SET [Master Output Table].[Area Change Ar Transfer From] = [Input table]![Amount 1723]
WHERE ((([Input table]![Transaction Type 1723])="Area Change Ar Transfer From") AND (([Master Output Table]![Transaction Type])="Amount 1723"));
```

Query 2

```
UPDATE [Master Output Table], [Input table] SET [Master Output Table].[Area Change Ar Transfer From] = [Input table]![Tax Amount 1723]
WHERE ((([Input table]![Transaction Type 1723])="Area Change Ar Transfer From") AND (([Master Output Table]![Transaction Type])="Tax Amount 1723"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
UPDATE [Master Output Table], [Input table]
SET 
[Master Output Table].[Area Change Ar Transfer From] = 
    case when [Master Output Table]![Transaction Type]="Amount 1723" then
    [Input table]![Amount 1723]
    else
    [Input table]![Tax Amount 1723]
end
WHERE 
[Input table]![Transaction Type 1723]="Area Change Ar Transfer From" 
AND 
[Master Output Table]![Transaction Type] in ("Amount 1723","Tax Amount 1723");
```

Comment: I get a syntax error (missing operator), which seems to be tied to the section beginning with 'case when'